# Prove that the set of points $P$ such that $PO_1^2-r_1^2=k(PO_2^2-r_2^2)$ is a circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

> Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be circles with respective centres $O_1$
>   and $O_2$ and respective radii $r_1$ and $r_2$. Let
>   $k\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$. Prove that the set of points $P$ such
>   that $$PO_1^2-r_1^2=k(PO_2^2-r_2^2)$$ is a circle.

It is clear to me how to do this algebraically. 
If I let $P$ be $(x,y)$, assume without loss of generality that $O_1$ is $(0,0)$ and let $O_2=(a,b)$, then 
$$x^2+y^2-r_1^2=k((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-r_2^2),$$
so
$$(k-1)x^2+(k-1)y^2-2kax-2kby+ka^2+kb^2-kr_2^2+r_1^2=0$$
and so on.

But is there an easy way of proving this geometrically?

Comment: The statement isn't true without some caveats. There are combinations of $O_1$, $r_1$, $O_2$, $r_2$ and $k$ where the resulting "circle" has an imaginary radius.

Comment: An example would be if $O_1=(0,0)$, $O_2=(1,0)$, $r_1=1$, $r_2=3$ and $k=0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the given condition is equivalent to $\dfrac {\sqrt {PO_1^2-r_1^2}}{\sqrt {(PO_2^2-r_2^2)}} =  \sqrt {k}$, a constant.

This satisfies the condition of a circle, the Apollonius circle.

Picture added:-

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it only be an [Apollonius circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius'_definition_of_a_circle) if $\frac {\sqrt {PO_1^2}}{\sqrt {PO_2^2}} =  m$, for some constant $m$?

Comment: @Jens Apollonius circle is built from two foci. They are the points of contacts of the tangents from P to the two circles.

Comment: I understand that. But the ratio of the distances from those foci must be a constant. When you include $r_1$ and $r_2$ in the equation, this doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: @Jens See picture added. Or draw one to verify that.

Comment: OK, but it seems to me the two foci wouldn't remain fixed points. Isn't that a pre-requisite?

Comment: @Jens That’s true. The initial position of P determines the foci and hence the corresponding Apollonius circle (called #P). If P is at some positions other than those on the circumference of #P, there will be another set of foci distinct from the previous set and hence another Apollonius circle distinct from #P. This is because the value of k is different now.